# Blender 2.8 exporting meshes materials with 0 opacity (G3DB/G3DJ) (LibGDX)

Tags: materials, export, transparency

I'm attempting to use LibGDX and an fbx-conv to create a 3D game as detailed [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX). The model loads but does not show so I decided to check the G3DJ file and found that the opacity was set to 0, changing this to 1 fixes the issue but I would rather use the binary G3DB file. The above tutorial mentions that to fix this you should "Go to the Material in Blender, and below "Transparency" set its Alpha to the desired one (usually 1, for full opacity)." but this was written pre 2.8 and I can't find this option anywhere. I'm guessing it has to do with [image: these options] but I'm not sure.

Comment: So I played around with the shading nodes for a it and changed the principled bsdf to just a diffuse bsdf but it didn't help, also it appears that diffuse is ""diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000]" and I'd like that to be 1, 1, 1, again nothing I do to the shader nodes appears to fix this :/ [Here](https://imgur.com/a/noA0xul) are pictures of the nodes and gd3j file.